# DbCommand can't run multiple SQL command in one ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dbcommand

Hello I have the following problem and I can't solve it.

With `DbCommand` I'm trying execute this SQL statement

```
Dim strCommnad As String = 
"CREATE DEFAULT [dbo].[DOMAIN_XLibPKID_D] AS (0);" + Environment.NewLine +                                 
"CREATE TYPE [dbo].[XLibPKID] FROM BIGINT NOT NULL;" + Environment.NewLine +
"EXEC sp_bindefault 'DOMAIN_XLibPKID_D', 'XLibPKID';"

command.CommandText = strCommnad              
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text                
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

but I always get this an error message

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'.

But when I run each command from `strCommand` standalone then everything works fine.

I'm using VS 2010 Professional and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try to run these three statements together in SQL Server Management Studio Express - it won't work either! You need to separate those out into two or three separate calls - they cannot be called in a single call ....

Comment: From [CREATE DEFAULT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173565.aspx): "This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do - but your approach seems overly complicated ...

You appear to be adding a `DEFAULT` clause to your `XLibPKID` column - right? This `ALTER TABLE` statement should do that, too:

```
command.CommandText = 
   "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DOMAIN_XLibPKID_D]  " +
   "    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_XLibPKID DEFAULT (0) FOR XLibPKID";
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This just adds a separate `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT` to your table.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding a `GO` between each statement:

```
Dim strCommnad As String =  "CREATE DEFAULT [dbo].[DOMAIN_XLibPKID_D] AS (0);" + Environment.NewLine +
"GO; CREATE TYPE [dbo].[XLibPKID] FROM BIGINT NOT NULL;" + Environment.NewLine + 
"GO; EXEC sp_bindefault 'DOMAIN_XLibPKID_D', 'XLibPKID';"
```

Comment: That won't work in a `DbCommand` or `SqlCommand` - GO is **NOT** a valid SQL keyword - it's a SQL Server Management Studio delimiter ONLY

Comment: Ah, bugger me! I'd never tried it outside of SSMS before - sorry.